# Copy attachments from list item to another list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, attachments, web

Case definition: i have item with attachments in list and i want to copy attachments to another list's item using web-forms and rest api probably

I tried to use GetByTitle('')/id/AttachmentFiles, but there was information like

```
"<d:ServerRelativeUrl>*mylist*/Attachments/*id*/*attachment*</d:ServerRelativeUrl>"
```

and i dont know how to exploit it. Maybe i can use SPServices or something like that instead of rest api?

Thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft flow as a workaround. I have two list "flow" and "test610" and I use the following flow to copy attachments from list "flow" to list "test610".

1.Manually trigger a flow > Get items > select your site and listA
[image]

2.Get attachments > select your site and listA > Create item > select your site and listB
[image]

3.Get attachment content > select your site and listB > Add attachment > select your site and listB
[image]

My Flow:
[image]

For Reference: [Copy Attachments from Existing SharePoint List to Document Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/82189/copy-attachments-from-existing-sharepoint-list-to.html)